# Salesforce as an IDP in Okta

Tags: salesforce, saml-2.0, okta

My requirement is that for salesforce users should be allowed to SSO(single sign on) in the my product which uses the Okta as the identity provider.

However the trouble is that in this case we want to use salesforce as the identity provider and my product as the service provider.

I understand that I would have do this via federated identities via SAML assertion. I was going through various references and was struggling to find the exact steps I would need to follow to achieve this case.

I could numerous example to add salesforce in the Okta as the service provider, but not the other way around.

Any help here would be appreciated...

Thanks, Rohit

Answer (score 0):

Rohit,

My understanding is that you need to configure Salesforce as an IdP and Okta (or your product) as the service provider.

This is a four step process 
Step 1. Creating your own Salesforce domain (Exact steps mentioned in the link below - Browse to the link I have given for detailed screenshots and steps for all these steps)
Step 2. Enable Identity Provider in Salesforce
Step 3. Creating Connected App in Salesforce
Step 4. Configure Single Sign On Settings in Okta

The exact steps are mentioned here (http://miniorange.com/salesforce-single-sign-on-(sso)) You need to jump to the section (much down below in the page that goes like this (Step-by-Step Guide to implement Salesforce as an Identity Provider (IdP) and Google Apps as a Service Provider) - The only difference is instead of using Google apps as a service provider, you will use Okta as a service provider so you need to find similar settings on Okta's console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anirban, let me try it and see how it goes!